# Combinatorics Equation

Tags: combinatorics

I am studying for a test on combinatorics and I recently came across this equation I had lost in my notes.
[image]

I do not really have a clue as to why this equation holds or its higher-level meaning. If anyone can offer some explanation as to why this equation is true for any positive integer k and non-negative integer n it would be greatly appreciated. It would even better if someone could give any insights on how I can prove this to be true so that it will be more mathematically intuitive.

Comment: Suggest checking the "multinomial theorem" [google or otherwise]

Comment: [This](https://brilliant.org/wiki/multinomial-theorem/#:~:text=The%20multinomial%20theorem%20describes%20how,with%20any%20number%20of%20terms.) should answer all your queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best shown with a simple example. The equation is rather scary in full generality, even though the concept it describes is simple.

Let's start with the simplest example: $(x+y)^2$. We can multiply this out to see

$$(x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2.$$

If I prime you by saying "pascal's triangle", you might notice that the coefficients of this expression $(1 \quad 2 \quad 1)$ form a row of pascal's triangle. Let's try the next one:

$$(x+y)^3 = x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3$$

The coefficients of *this* $(1 \quad 3 \quad 3 \quad 1)$ are *also* a row of pascal's triangle. You may or may not be aware of this (shocking!) connection, but in general

$$(x+y)^n = \text{something } x^n + \text{something } x^{n-1}y + \ldots + \text{something } xy^{n-1} + \text{something } y^n$$

It turns out that these "somethings" will *always* be the $n$th row of pascal's triangle!

---

Let's take a moment to think about that. This is one of the places where mathematics exists to let us be lazy! If you wanted to expand out $(x+y)^{100}$, you would spend all day doing it if you wanted to distribute everything out. Moreover you would almost *certainly* make a mistake somewhere along the way. But this gives us a quick trick™️ for computing these easily! Simply find the $100$th row of pascal's triangle (which is easy, if tedious, to do) and we're done.

Of course, this still sounds tedious... Is there a way for us to be lazier?

Always!

---

The next step comes from *combinatorics*, which is why you're being taught this. Let's think about what the coefficients *really mean* in these expressions. *Why* do we have $1 \quad 3 \quad 3 \quad 1$ showing up here?

Well, let's do some distribution and see what happens:

$$(x+y)^2 = xx + \color{green}{xy + yx} + yy$$

$$(x+y)^3 = xxx + \color{blue}{xyy + yxy + yyx} + \color{red}{xxy + xyx + yxx} + yyy$$

Notice what's happening! When we do the distribution, we get every possible choice of $x$s and $y$s. Then, since $xy = yx$, we can reorder them so that they all look like $x^iy^{n-i}$. So our coefficient on $x^i y^{n-i}$ is exactly the number of ways to have $i$ xs and $n-i$ ys in a term!

But we *know* what that coefficient is! We want to count the number of ways to have $i$ xs and $n-i$ ys in a string of length $n$. This is what binomial coefficients are *made* for!

$$\text{The coefficient of } x^iy^{n-i} \text{ is } \frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}$$

We write this as $\binom{n}{i}$, but this is kind of a special case. When we only have $x$ and $y$, things are easy. If we know where the xs go, we have no choice where to put the ys! More generaly we could write this as $\binom{n}{i, n-i}$ to indicate we're choosing $i$ xs and $n-i$ ys.

---

Ok, last step! What are these *multinomial* coefficients floating around? Well, they exist to solve this same problem for more variables!

Say you want to calculate $(x+y+z)^{10}$, but you're too lazy to expand it out. Keeping in mind what we've done so far, you might come up with a clever strategy:

You notice the terms of $(x+y+z)^{10}$ are going to be all of the strings of $10$ xs, ys, and zs. Then the coefficient of $x^i y^j z^{10 - i - j}$ is going to be exactly the number of ways you can choose that string.

Again, we know the answer to this problem! How many ways are there to split $10$ things into $3$ groups of size $i$ $j$ and $10-i-j$? There's exactly

$$\binom{10}{i, j, 10-i-j} = \frac{10!}{i! j! (10 - i - j)!}$$

many ways to do this. So that is the coefficient!

---

More generally, if you want the coefficient of $x^iy^jz^kw^l$ in $(x+y+z+w)^n$, you know what to do! It's $\binom{n}{i,j,k,l}$. Of course, we should have $i+j+k+l = n$, since each term will have $n$ letters in total.

And now, finally, we find ourselves with the formula you started with.

What is $(x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_k)^n$?

Well, the coefficient of $x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}\ldots x_k^{i_k}$ is exactly $\binom{n}{i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k}$. So if we want to express this as a sum, we see:

$$(x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_k)^n = \sum \binom{n}{i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k} x_1^{i_1} x_2^{i_2} \ldots x_k^{i_k}$$

here the constraint on the sum is, again, that $i_1 + i_2 + \ldots + i_k = n$. Because there must still be $n$ letters in any given term.

But people don't like writing $x_1 \ldots x_n$, so we write it using $\prod$ instead. This gives us exactly the formula that you were initially asking about:

$$(x_1 + x_2 + \ldots x_k)^n = \sum_{i_1 + \ldots + i_k = n} \binom{n}{i_1, i_2, \ldots i_k} \prod x_j^{i_j}$$

---

As some quick exercises to see that you understand:

1. What is the coefficient of $x^3 y^2 z^4$ in $(x+y+z)^9$?
2. Can you expand out in full the polynomial $(w+x+y+z)^3$ without foiling?

---

I hope this helps ^_^